# jProfiler not giving method level statistics

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

I have installed `jProfiler` in my Linux machine and I am saving the data into .jps file. I am then loading this file into `jProfiler` UI in my local machine.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <nextId id="104" />
  <generalSettings setupHasRun="false">
    <recordingProfiles>
      <recordingProfile  id="10" name="CPU recording">
            <actionKey id="cpu"/>
      </recordingProfile>
    </recordingProfiles>
  </generalSettings>
  <templates>
    <template id="50" name="Instrumentation, all features supported" startFrozen="false" recordCPUOnStartup="false" vmCannotExit="false" instrumentationType="1" samplingNoFilters="false" lineNumbers="false" samplingFrequency="5" timeType="1" disableCPUProfiling="false" recordAllocOnStartup="true" recordArrayAlloc="true" enableTriggersOnStartup="true" allocTreeRecordingType="1" disableMonitorContentions="false" componentDetection="true" chronoHeap="false" autoUpdatePeriodLong="5" autoUpdatePeriodShort="2" allUrls="false" payloadCap="50" eventCap="20000" showSystemThreads="false" utilConcurrentHandling="true" libraryDebugParameters="" exceptionalCap="5" exceptionalTimeType="4" autoTuneInstrumentation="true" autoTuneMaxAverage="100" autoTuneMinPerMille="10" samplingPayloadCallStacks="true" description="This is JProfiler's fully featured mode. In this setting, call stack information is accurate, but CPU overhead and distortion of measured call times may be high, depending on your filter settings. You should define inclusive filters for your own packages." system="true" />
    <template id="51" name="Sampling for CPU profiling, some features not supported" startFrozen="false" recordCPUOnStartup="false" vmCannotExit="false" instrumentationType="3" samplingNoFilters="false" lineNumbers="false" samplingFrequency="5" timeType="1" disableCPUProfiling="false" recordAllocOnStartup="true" recordArrayAlloc="true" enableTriggersOnStartup="true" allocTreeRecordingType="1" disableMonitorContentions="false" componentDetection="true" chronoHeap="false" autoUpdatePeriodLong="5" autoUpdatePeriodShort="2" allUrls="false" payloadCap="50" eventCap="20000" showSystemThreads="false" utilConcurrentHandling="true" libraryDebugParameters="" exceptionalCap="5" exceptionalTimeType="4" autoTuneInstrumentation="true" autoTuneMaxAverage="100" autoTuneMinPerMille="10" samplingPayloadCallStacks="true" description="This template is particularly suitable for CPU profiling and for memory profiling when accurate allocation information is not important. Sampling has a very low overhead and does not distort measured call tines. Some views, like the method statistics are no available. JEE payloads cannot be annotated in the call tree, but payload hotspots without backtraces are available." system="true" />
  </templates>
  <sessions>
    <session id="80" templateId="50" name="Animated Bezier Curve Demo" type="1" isStartupWorkingDirectory="true" mainClass="bezier.BezierAnim">
      <filters>
        <filter type="inclusive" name="com." />
      </filters>
      <exceptionalMethods/>
      <classPath>
        <classPathEntry path="demo/bezier/classes" />
      </classPath>
      <sourcePath>
        <sourcePathEntry path="demo/bezier/src" />
      </sourcePath>
      <probes>
        <probe name="com.jprofiler.agent.probe.interceptor.TrackingInterceptor" enabled="true" startProbeRecording="false" events="false" annotatePayloads="false">
          <id value="3" />
        </probe>
      </probes>
    </session>
```

The problem which I am facing is that I am not able to get any details regarding method statistics under the CPU views tab in `jProfiler` UI.

But I am able to get other fields in Telemetrics.

The version in use: JProfiler 9.1 and I have used sample config.xml to start with my test. DO i need to make any changed in my config file to get the method level statistics in my .jps file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method statistics is recorded separately, because the overhead is too high to always be recorded together with CPU data.

When the session is live, go the method statistics view and enabled recording. For offline profiling, there is a trigger action that starts method statistics recording.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide an example to add trigger code in the config.xml file.

Comment: You have to configure the trigger in the GUI, the config file format is not intended to be written manually. For more information see http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/config/triggers.html

Comment: Hi, I created a new session and added the triggers in GUI for methods. But where to get the config file for the new session? so that i can place it in my machine and use this session id while profiling

Comment: Use Session->Export session settings

Comment: Thanks Ingo, While choosing for method level triggering, Option 2 asks to Specify methods. What should i specify if i want to profile all the methods and also having very long list of methods. Can i just leave it blank in that case?so that it profiles all the available methods?

Comment: The methods in a method trigger are not the methods that you want to profile, but the methods that trigger the associated actions. Don't use a method trigger, use a "JVM startup" trigger and add a "Start recording" action to it.